# Why different behaviors on combinations() if empty list is used in Groovy/Spock?

Tags: groovy, spock

We came across a strange behavior of combinations() in Spock with its interaction with empty list.

1) A simple case that's working ok

```
def testa = [[1,2], [2,3], [3,4]].combinations()

[[1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3], 
 [1, 3, 3], [2, 3, 3],
 [1, 2, 4], [2, 2, 4], 
 [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
```

2) When you pass an empty string at the head of the list, it seems to ignore the first entry and produce something reasonable:

```
def testb = [[], [2,3], [3,4]].combinations()

[[2, 3], [3, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
```

3) But.... when you pass an empty string anywhere other than the beginning, it seems to ignore everything ahead of it:

```
def testc = [[1,2], [], [3,4]].combinations()

[[3], [4]]
```

And here's another example:

```
def testd = [[1,2], [2,3], []].combinations()

[]
```

Anyone has any explanation of what happens here? Why totally different behaviors depending on where the empty list appears? We'd like to make sense of the rules so we can use this combinations() properly.

Comment: Thank you @tim_yates for making it pretty! :-)

Answer (score 1):

We can work [though the source of `combinations`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/util/GroovyCollections.java#L91) and find out what it does.

Here, I've converted it to Groovy, and added debug so we can see what it is doing:

```
List combinations( Iterable collections ) {
    List collectedCombos = []
    collections.each { collection ->
        collection = collection instanceof Collection ? collection : [ collection ]
        println "Handling $collection"
        if( collectedCombos.isEmpty() ) {
            collectedCombos = collection.collect { item -> [ item ] }
            println "collectedCombos was empty, is now: $collectedCombos"
        }
        else {
            collectedCombos = collection.collectMany { value ->
                print "Appending $value to $collectedCombos"
                def result = collectedCombos.collect { List savedCombo ->
                    savedCombo.collect() << value
                }
                println " gave us $result"
                result
            }
            println "So now, collectedCombos is $collectedCombos"
        }
    }
    collectedCombos
}
```

So, if we give it:

```
combinations( [[1,2], [2,3], [3,4]] )
```

we get the output:

```
Handling [1, 2]
collectedCombos was empty, is now: [[1], [2]]
Handling [2, 3]
Appending 2 to [[1], [2]] gave us [[1, 2], [2, 2]]
Appending 3 to [[1], [2]] gave us [[1, 3], [2, 3]]
So now, collectedCombos is [[1, 2], [2, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
Handling [3, 4]
Appending 3 to [[1, 2], [2, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]] gave us [[1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3], [2, 3, 3]]
Appending 4 to [[1, 2], [2, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]] gave us [[1, 2, 4], [2, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
So now, collectedCombos is [[1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3], [2, 3, 3], [1, 2, 4], [2, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
```

and running with an initial empty set:

```
combinations( [[], [2,3], [3,4]] )
```

Causes the `isEmpty` conditional to fire twice:

```
Handling []
collectedCombos was empty, is now: []
Handling [2, 3]
collectedCombos was empty, is now: [[2], [3]]
Handling [3, 4]
Appending 3 to [[2], [3]] gave us [[2, 3], [3, 3]]
Appending 4 to [[2], [3]] gave us [[2, 4], [3, 4]]
So now, collectedCombos is [[2, 3], [3, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
```

Putting the empty list in the middle:

```
combinations( [[1,2], [], [3,4]] )
```

Shows:

```
Handling [1, 2]
collectedCombos was empty, is now: [[1], [2]]
Handling []
So now, collectedCombos is []
Handling [3, 4]
collectedCombos was empty, is now: [[3], [4]]
```

As you can see, no data is generated for the loop round the second element, and then this empty list overwrites any data we had originally.

For the third case, it will be the same, but as the empty list is last, the result will be an empty list.

Hope this explains it?

#### Edit:

If you want to handle empty lists in your input list, then you can do something like this:

```
[[1,2], [], [3,4]].findResults { it ?: [ 'x' ] }.combinations()
```

To give:

```
[[1,'x',3], [2,'x',3], [1,'x',4], [2,'x',4]]
```

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates for answering. I still think the case where the null list is in the middle does not make sense. If you already got [[1], [2]], and now you want to handle [], why does it return [], and not [[1], [2]]? Sorry... this comment form is very limited.

Comment: @ShintaSmith because when you have an empty list, it calls `List newCombos = new ArrayList();` followed immediately by `collectedCombos = newCombos;`

Comment: @ShintaSmith that's lines 103 to 111 in the file I linked to at the start

Comment: Hi, @tim_yates, thanks! But I don't mean to ask where the code that generates the null list. I am questioning whether that's the right behavior of combinations(). To me, the function combinations() should always grow the result list, never to truncate. We already got [[1], [2]] as the result of handling the 1st element. If now we're handling 2nd element, which is [], it should just return [[1], [2]] as result. Doesn't this look like a bug to you?